# how to do this kind of substitution in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In case that I don't want to use mma's Erfc or Erf functions, I want to define my own

```
myErf[x_] := Integrate[Exp[-y^2/2], {y, -Infinity, x}];
```

And then I want mma to substitute any evalulation of integral with myErf[x], for example:

```
Integrate[Exp[-y^2+y/2], {y, x, Infinity}]
```

How to do this? Or in general, how to ask mma to evaluate an expression using the function I'd like it to use, instead of its own built in one? Is there any way of doing this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what kind of substitution you are looking for. Could you post the desired result?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to (easily) override the behaviour of `Integrate` like that. The only two options I can think of is 1) You write your own integration function that searches for the `Erf` type integrands then passes the rest back to Integrate. 2) You catch and rewrite the `Erf`'s after mma's `Integrate` has done its magic.

Comment: @Simon Anyway, any approach I think of has many holes ...

Comment: @belisarius Probably. @Qiang Li: Can you tell us your motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: @belisarius: I believe the desired result in this case is: 1/Sqrt[2]*Exp[1/16]*myErf[Sqrt[2]*(-1/4+x)]

Comment: @Simon: the motivation to do this is that sometimes, I want to convert expressions using different un-evaluated functions. I want to do this automatically in mma. many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I meant in my comment is that the naive

```
Unprotect[Integrate];
Integrate[Exp[-y_^2], {y_, -\[Infinity], x_}] := myErf[x]
```

to try to intercept some `Integrate` evaluations does not work.

---

*Actually* it does work

```
In[]:= Integrate[Exp[-y^2],{y,-Infinity,z}]
Out[]= myErf[z]
```

(that will teach me for answering a SO question at midnight).
So maybe you don't need the `myIntegrate` function given below.

---

Anyway...  The two alternatives given in the comment are:

**1)** You could write your own `Erf` integrator using something like

```
In[1]:= myErf[x_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[Exp[-y^2],{y,-\[Infinity],x}] 
(* sames as Erf up to constant and scaling *)

In[2]:= Clear[myIntegrate]
        myIntegrate[a_. Exp[b_. y_^2], {y_, -\[Infinity], x_}] /; FreeQ[{a, b}, y] := ConditionalExpression[myErf[x], b < 0]
        myIntegrate[a_. Exp[b_. y_^2], {y_, xx_, x_}] := myIntegrate[a Exp[b y^2], {y, -\[Infinity], x}] - myIntegrate[a Exp[b y^2], {y, -\[Infinity], xx}]
        myIntegrate[a_ + b_, lims__] := myIntegrate[a, lims] + myIntegrate[b, lims] (* assuming this is ok *)
        myIntegrate[expr_, lims__] := Integrate[expr, lims]

In[8]:= myIntegrate[a Exp[x]+b Exp[-b x^2],{x,2y,z}]
Out[8]= ConditionalExpression[a (-E^(2 y)+E^z) - myErf[2 y] + myErf[z], b > 0]
```

Where at the end, the remaining integrals are passed to `Integrate`. But you'd have to be smarter in the pattern matching (maybe including some transformations in intermediate steps) in order to catch all `Erf`-like functions.

**2)**
You overwrite the `Erf`-type functions so that they never evaluate using the built-in routines:

```
In[9]:= Clear[myErf];
        Unprotect[Erf,Erfc,Erfi];
In[10]:= Erf[x__] := myErf[x]
         Erfc[x__]:= myErfc[x]
         Erfi[x__]:= myErfi[x]

In[13]:= {Erf[1], Erfc[2],  Erfi[\[Pi]], Integrate[E^-x^2,x]}
Out[13]= {myErf[1],  myErfc[2], myErfi[\[Pi]], 1/2 Sqrt[Pi] myErf[x]}
```

Where, obviously, you choose your own conventions for the `myErf` functions.

---

**Edit:**
The simplest and maybe safest/softest method (thanks to Leonid) of doing what you want is to just `Block[{Erf=...},...]` and let the Mathematica integrator do all of the work.
For example you `myErf` was given as

```
In[1]:= myErf[x] == Integrate[Exp[-y^2/2], {y, -Infinity, x}]
Out[1]= myErf[x]==Sqrt[Pi/2] (1+Erf[x/Sqrt[2]])
```

So to solve the integral in your original post,

```
In[2]:= Block[{Erf = (Sqrt[2/Pi]*myErf[Sqrt[2] #] - 1 &)}, 
          Integrate[Exp[-y^2 + y/2], {y, x, Infinity}]]
Out[2]= (E^(1/16)(Sqrt[\[Pi]] (-1 + 4 x + Sqrt[(-1 + 4 x)^2]) + 
          Sqrt[2] (1 - 4 x) myErf[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(-(1/4) + x)^2]])
        )/(2 Sqrt[(1 - 4 x)^2])
```

---

**Edit 2:**
Maybe you just need to be able to translate to and from `myErf` expressions. 
This means that it won't be automatic, but it will be flexible. Try

```
In[1]:= toMyErf=(FunctionExpand[#]/.Erf:>(Sqrt[2/Pi]*myErf[Sqrt[2] #]-1&)&);
        fromMyErf=(#/.myErf:>(Sqrt[Pi/2] (1+Erf[#/Sqrt[2]])&)&);

In[3]:= Integrate[Exp[-y^2+y/2],{y,x,Infinity}]//toMyErf
Out[3]= 1/2 E^(1/16) Sqrt[\[Pi]] (2-Sqrt[2/\[Pi]] myErf[Sqrt[2] (-(1/4)+x)])
In[4]:= D[x*myErf[x+x^2],x]//fromMyErf//toMyErf
Out[4]= E^(-(1/2) (x+x^2)^2) x (1+2 x)+myErf[x+x^2]
```

Note that the `FunctionExpand` command is there to rewrite `Erfc[x]` as `1-Erf[x]`. You might want to implement that part slightly better.

Comment: +1 for showing hints on how to define your own integrator. Not sure if _this_ particular case is worth. Not your fault.

Comment: thanks a lot for the update. It works. But maybe I am demanding too much. What if I have another requirement to get derivatives on myErf[x], for example, Block[{Erf = (Sqrt[2/Pi]*myErf[Sqrt[2] #] - 1 &)}, 
 D[x*myErf[x + x^2], x]] does not work.

Comment: @Qiang Li: See new addition. Maybe it's just best if you can simply translate between the `Erf` and `myErf` functions.

Comment: this is great. I am accepting your answer. Could you please explain why you meant by "if you can simply translate between the Erf and myErf functions."

Comment: @Qiang Li: I only meant what I wrote in "Edit 2". That is, you manually translate as opposed to making it automatic.

Answer (score 3):

A softer way is to use `UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[withMyErf];
SetAttributes[withMyErf, HoldAll];
withMyErf[code_] :=
Block[{Exp},
 Exp /: Integrate[Exp[(a : _ : 1)*x_^2], {x_, t0_, t_}] :=
   ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[Pi]*(myErf[Sqrt[-a]*t] - myErf[Sqrt[-a]*t0]))/(2*Sqrt[-a]), 
   Re[a] < 0];
code]
```

Example:

```
In[4]:= withMyErf[Integrate[Exp[-3*x^2], {x, -Infinity, t}]]

Out[4]= 1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/3] (myErf[Sqrt[3] t] - myErf[-\[Infinity]])
```

outside of our custom "dynamic scoping construct", everything will work as usual. Put the code where you want this to happen inside it. And, no changes ever made to `Integrate`, which can be dangerous. All we risk here is that Exp will not evaluate, but most symbolic transformation rules for it are anyway local rules, I guess.

Edit:

To answer the general question, if you want to alter the standard way Mathematica evaluates things, you have several choices. Some of them have been mentioned in the previous answers, I just want to summarize them on a little more abstract level. Given an expression `f[g[something]]`, typically you can:

- Redefine DownValues for `g` - this will work if you want `g` to be rewritten into something else
  before `f` "sees" it, but only if `f` does not hold its argument in position where `g[something]`
  stands
- Add an `UpValue` for `g`, with respect to expression `f[g[_]]` or similar. This will work if you 
  want to alter the behavior of `f` in a soft way, that is, only on arguments of form matching the 
  `UpValue` definition (`f[g[_]]`  in this case). For this to work, either `g` should not have 
  `DownValues` matching `g[something]` (so that it does not evaluate), or `f` should hold its 
  argument. This is a typical use case when `f` is system function and `g` is user-defined, since 
  this is the softest way to alter the behavior of the system function - note that while `f` 
  behaves differently, the rule is attached to `g`.
- Add a `DownValue` to `f`. This is a "hard" way. Will work either if `f` holds its argument, or if
  g[something] will not by itself evaluate to something else, or you will have to temporarily add 
  Hold - attribute  to `f`, which is even more intrusive. If `f` is a system function, then this 
  method is a last resort. Especially avoid this if `f` is a non-trivial or frequently used and 
  important built-in function, because it is hard to anticipate all the consequences of such 
  modifications, while many system functions are using other system functions on the top level.
- Write your own lexical scoping constructs, which will analyze the code in unevaluated form and 
  do the proper substitutions, and only then allow the code to evaluate. This will require that you
  have access to your code in one piece (that is, the code must exist in the form you want from the 
  start), which is a severe restriction, so in practice this option is ruled out in most cases.

There is also a `Block` trick, which allows you to "localize the damage" by making such redefinitions dynamically local to a block of code where you want them to apply. In some cases, I find it indispensable, because it allows ways to non-locally control the evaluation process which are not easily reproduced by other language constructs.

Comment: Soft ways are for soft people! (And people who care about the possible unwanted side effects of their code...  +1)

Comment: @Simon I used to think this way too. Until one day I got a bug which took me several days to figure out, and boy was it hard. I am more careful these days, but admittedly softer as well - so you're right, in a way :)

Comment: @Leonid: why doesn't withMyErf[Integrate[Exp[-x^2 + x/2], {x, -Infinity, t}]] work? can you please explain a bit? many thanks.

Comment: @Qiang Li: Obviously, the pattern is not general enough, it only matches when there is a square term and nothing else. My main point was to illustrate how this can be done with UpValues, not to provide the most general solution. You can extend the pattern to match your expression as well, by adding something like `+(c:_:1)*x+(d:_:0)` to the square-term pattern, and perhaps changing the r.h.s. to a correspondingly more general form as well.

Comment: @Simon, @Leonid: I still could not get the desired result 1/Sqrt[2]*Exp[1/16]*myErf[Sqrt[2]*(-1/4+x)] for the expression Integrate[Exp[-y^2+y/2], {y, x, Infinity}] using this method. Would you please provide a working example? Many thanks.

Comment: @Qiang Li: Just blocking Erf is probably the simplest method - i.e. you never have to worry about writing your own integrator. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Simon: oh, let me try with that. BTW, how to remove the effect of Unprotect and then re-definition? I found Clear or ClearAll does not work; I had to restart mma. many thanks

Comment: @Qiang Li: Use `Unset` to remove the definition. So to reverse `Unprotect[Erf]; Erf[x__] := myErf[x]` you should run `Erf[x__] =.; Protect[Erf]`.  Note that the Pattern on the RHS has to be identical.